# Vat Number missing in Billing Address Magento 2

Tags: magento2, checkout, shipping-address, billing-address, vat

I am trying to checkout as a Guest and when I proceed to the Payment Step, I have checked the data saved in the Shipping Step and I found that Vat Number is missing in the Billing Address, but in Shipping Address is filled. Does anybody know if it is a bug or a missing configuration?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

That is a bug currently in Magento 2.3.?, which can be fixed by either updating to 2.3.4 when its released, or by applying this patch in file `app/code/Magento/Customer/Model/Address/CustomerAddressDataFormatter.php` by adding `vat_id`:

https://github.com/magento/magento2/commit/0f38f03418d4228e4e3c4898f9e95508ecef25ca